# Docker bind user file ownership

Tags: docker, permissions, file-permissions, mount

It was provided to me an image that run a service with the root user.

I have the need to bind mount a directory where the service running in the container must create files that will be used as input files of another non-containerized service.

The problem is well know: the generated files keep UID and GID from the in-container user.

So, I tried with this config:

```
  myservice:
    image: "someonewho/liketorunwithroot: latest"
    user: "${UID}:${GID}"
    volumes:
       - type: bind
         source: /home/user/output
         target: /service/path/outputdir
       - type: bind
         source: /etc/passwd
         target: /etc/passwd
       - type: bind
         source: /etc/group
         target: /etc/group
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

doing like this, I can force the in-container user to use uid and gid that are the same of the user on the docker host, so I have no problem at all with the files generated under `/service/path/outputdir`.

But in this way the service is not working anymore, because the user with those ID can't read and write in other folders.

So I tried with the user namespace, forcing the range of subuid to one specif id (the same of the docker host user)

In this case I get this error:

`docker: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file (exit status 1): Container ID 100 cannot be mapped to a host ID.`

I can't manipulate the Dockerfile, nor the container, because it must be "portable".

Is there a solution?

Comment: Can you build a new image based on the portable one or is that also off limits?

Comment: @HansKilian nope, because I couldn't share the new image

Answer (score 0):

you should consider using docker volumes for storing the files, you can always [backup, restore or migrate the data](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes)

```yaml
  myservice:
    image: "someonewho/liketorunwithroot: latest"
    volumes:
       - output:/service/path/outputdir
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  volumes:
    output:
```

and you get get the volume name with

```sh
docker volume ls --format '{{json .}}' | jq -r '.Name' | grep "$(basename $PWD)_output"
```

Comment: I can't use volumes, because the output files of the service are used as input files of another non-containerized service.

Comment: that should not be a problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with is running this on the host

```
mkdir container-files
chmod g+s container-files
docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/container-files:/output ubuntu bash -c "echo test > /output/test.txt"
```

Now there's a file in the container-files directory that was created by a container running as root:root. But on the host, the file is owned by `root:your group`. And since you're in `your group`, you can read the file. Unfortunately, you can't do much else with it.

It uses the SGID bit on the container-files directory, so files created in the directory will have the same group ownership as the container-files directory.
On my Linux machine, the s-bit is set by default when the directory is created, so you might not need to run `chmod`.

The best solution, though, is to change the container so it doesn't need to run as root. I don't see how running as root is more portable. In fact, there are container environments that don't allow containers to run as root due to the security risks it poses (OpenShift).